# How to set up an Access Point / WiFi Repeater to connect through Bluetooth?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, pi-4, systemd-networkd, wpa-supplicant

I had successfully set up my raspberry pi as an access point as WiFi repeater followed this guide: [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with a bridge.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge)

I would like to set up my raspberry pi so that other device can get connect and get WiFi as well as internet connection through Bluetooth.

Thank you.